# How to copy data from parquet source to delta destination in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to copy data from parquet source to delta destination in Azure data factory

Answer (score 0):

Create Linked services for both Parquet source and destination in the Azure Data Factory. Then create datasets for both source and sink to get their corresponding schemas. Then use a Copy Data activity and provide the necessary source and sink configurations in the corresponding fields of Copy data activity. Validate the pipeline and trigger the debug run of pipeline. Verify the data that was migrated to the destination.